# Get ContextMenu Datacontext of Parent

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

I have a ContextMenu binded to a CommandBinding:

```
<MetroTreeView:MetroTreeView x:Name="tvTagList" Grid.Row="1" Margin="15, 0, 15, 0" SelectedItemChanged="tvTagList_SelectedTagChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ExtryzeAccentBrushSecondary}" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="White"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
<MetroTreeView:MetroTreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type  DataBind:TagClass}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding TagClassMagic}" />
                <Run Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrushSecondary}" Text=" - " />
                <Run Foreground="{StaticResource TextBrushSecondary}" Text="{Binding Path=Description, Converter={StaticResource IValueTagDescriptionCleanup}}" />
            </TextBlock>
            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Dump Tag List..." Click="DumpClassTagList" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataBind:TagEntry}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.CommandBindings>
                        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static DataBind:HaloMap.CommandTagBookmarking }"
                                            CanExecute="CommandTagBookmarking_CanExecute"
                                            Executed="CommandTagBookmarking_Executed"
                                            />
                    </ContextMenu.CommandBindings>
                    <MenuItem Header="Bookmark Tag" Foreground="White" Command="{x:Static DataBind:HaloMap.CommandTagBookmarking}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TagFileName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</MetroTreeView:MetroTreeView.Resources>
<MetroTreeView:MetroTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MetroTreeView:MetroTreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MetroTreeView:MetroTreeViewItem}}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="tvTagList_ItemDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
</MetroTreeView:MetroTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But when I run the `CanExecute` command, every attempt to access the DataContext is always met with a null:

```
private void CommandTagBookmarking_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var a = e.Source;
    var b = ((MenuItem)a).DataContext;
    var c = ((ContextMenu) ((MenuItem) e.Source).Parent).DataContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Comment: nope, "var c = ((ContextMenu) ((MenuItem) e.Source).Parent).DataContext;" is still returning null.

Comment: @AlexReed I suggest you use `Snoop` to inspect the running application and see where the gap is.

Comment: Snoop doesn't even acknowledge my application is running.

Comment: @AlexReed It can't be possible. What .Net version are you compiling against?

Comment: .NET 4.0, in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @AlexReed you need to click and drag the right crosshairs button into the application.

Comment: @AlexReed no, that looks like an old version. Get it from [here](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: According to Snoop, the stackpanel's context menu doesn't exist: http://i.imgur.com/Ad7iq11.png

Comment: @AlexReed not true. The `ContextMenu` is inside a `Popup` which is not part of the Visual Tree, that's precisely why you're not seeing it in the Visual Tree.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ContextMenu` don't lie in the `VisualTree` of the object where it's placed. You have to inherit the `DataContext` of object using `PlacementTarget` -

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext,
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```